# How do I run Deus Ex: Human Revolution in windowed mode?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I've been poking around in the options menu, trying to find a option for window mode. But, I can't seem to find any.

So, is there any way to get this game running in windowed mode?

Comment: You could try [this](http://forums.techarena.in/video-games/1426636.htm#post5395770) registry hack which involves removing your user's rights to the key which allegedly controls fullscreen.

Comment: @Nick Too bad it's onyly for DX11 :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the latest patch, windowed mode has been added.

> - Added windowed mode.

[Source](http://store.steampowered.com/news/6272/)

Comment: niiiice!  I love windowed mode

Answer (score 2):

No, this does not appear to be possible at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Fullscreen is not supported out of the box but there is a dirty hack:

> 1. regedit in cmd
> 2. look for folder `computer\H_KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Eidos\Deus Ex: HR\Graphics`
> 3. look for fullscren (double click, set value to 0, LEAVE REGEDIT UP)
> 4. open explorer to steam>common>deus ex: human revolution folder
> 5. Hold left shift while double clicking `dxhr.exe`
>
> ### Important Notes
>
> 1. **You have to run this in DirectX 11**, anything else seems to make it *exremely* bright for no reason.
> 2. Do not alt-tab, ever. *ever*, *EVER*, ***EVER***!
> 3. You may have to repeat steps 3 to 5 (which is why you leave regedit up)
> 4. You will most likely have to keep repeating this process, I saw someone on reddit earlier say it wasn’t working, you just gotta keep at it brosephs

[Source](http://projectleet.com/?p=163)

Comment: The method I linked modifies registry key permissions to deny access to change it to the current user, which may be the reason behind leaving `regedit` open

Comment: I have to admit that the whole never, ever alt-tab kinda defeats the purpose of windowed mode as well. So sad that the devs didn't support windowed mode on the PC port.

Answer (score 0):

Alt-Enter works - at least with the latest patch.